# sinon.match() dont match object with Json.stringify response

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am testing a simple express route that returns a json object and usin mocha with sinon to match the response.

This is the simple express response /login

```
            const login = async (req, res) => {
                let response = {
                    success: true,
                    id: "id0090",
                }
                res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
```

This is the simple tet with micha and sinon

```
it('res.end should be called with success true ', async () => {
    let req = {
        body: {}
    }
    let res = {
        end: sinon.spy(),
    }
    await login(req,res);
    let expected = {
        success: true,
        id: "id0090",
    }
    sinon.assert.calledWith(res.end, sinon.match(expected));

});
```

I get this error but as you see both are the same.

```
            AssertError: expected end to be called with arguments 
            {"success":true,"id":"id0090"} match(success: true, id: id0090)
```

Somethign interesting is that if i remove `JSON.stringify` from `login` the test pass but this is not the idea.

```
            const login = async (req, res) => {
                let response = {
                    success: true,
                    id: "id0090",
                }
                res.end(response); // this make the test pass
            }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

because JSON.stringify convert to string but the expected result is a JSON object so it failed.